# I need a battery for a Bulls Alpine Hawk bike that I bought used

Tags: electric-bike, battery

I bought a Bulls bike and the battery would take an OK charge. After several months I charged the battery with the cables provided. I took a 15 mile ride and my average speed was 11mph. I'm now trying to find a replacement battery. The battery is labeled: Evation Drivepack 1807161076 FAZUAGmbH; it is from Germany.

Comment: Have you tried the shop?   https://shop.fazua.com/collections/ride-50-t-s

Comment: Batteries are consumable items - most are good for about 1000 charges, but some might only take 500.  Budget to buy a replacement, or ask a battery repacking shop locally if they can re-pack your existing battery.